# Error while building up multicontainer app PostgreSQL and pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I'm trying to build multi-container app that includes PostgreSQL and pgadmin4 with single docker-compose file. But I'm getting stuck here.

[image: I'm stuck here]

[This is my docker-compose file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HfTuKbHKPJJw86fXR-gCaysBrgdfQu2J/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: State your question? What seems to be the issue?

Comment: I'm wondering: why did you post a text file as an image?

Comment: I'd like to rephrase what @JimJones said: please **do not** post text as images. This makes your question much less discoverable, makes it harder for people trying to help you (because we can't copy/paste your code or configuration), and if those image links expire, the question becomes meaningless to future readers.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I later realized that both services were running properly. Its only that I'm not getting any confirmation on the CLI but I'm able to access from browser.